# Any experiences with WeSetupYourWebViewApp?

Tags: apache, cordova, webview

I am sick doing all this WebView setup stuff for iOS and Android. Don't like Phonegap/Apache Cordova either as it's very complicated with all these optional plugins.
Anyone tried out [WeSetupYourWebViewApp](http://www.wesetupyourwebviewapp.com) or similar services?

Would be happy for any recommendation!

Thanks and have a great day! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one responded, I tried it. For me it worked quite well, feel free to contact me if you have any questions.